# Узнать координаты Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

На WPF странице есть родительский контейнер `canvas` в котором расположены несколько `grid`, как получить координаты `Point` одного из этих `grid` ?

```
            <Canvas Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Black" Name="cavRoot">
            <Grid x:Name="_Settings"  Height="600" Width="400"  Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="20">
                //
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Методы [Canvas.GetTop(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.gettop(v=vs.110).aspx) и [Canvas.GetLeft(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.getleft(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ссылки на ресурсы лучше оформлять через встроенный функционал markdown: `[визуальное имя для ссылки](ссылка)`

Comment: @AlexKrass Спасибо. Знал об этом, да не подумал применить.